# Specify line length powershell

Tags: powershell, powershell-3.0

I need to specify the line lenght with powershell.
I have a source file with lines with different line lenghts and i need to export them to a new file with all the same line lengths, 470.
I found a command but this will add some with spaces in front of the line and i need to add the spaces at the end of the line.

```
$sourcefile = '.\file.txt'
foreach ($row in $sourcefile) {
$row = [string]::Format("{0,469}",$row) | out-file '.\newfile.txt' -append }
```

Comment: found it! I need to use a negative number. {0,-496}

Answer (score 3):

Use a negative number to specify left alignment in a given space.

Eg.

```
'#{0,-10}#' -f 43
```

outputs:

```
#43        #
```